# Puppeteer focus loop through input fields

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've got a page with 50 input fields that I'm trying to change the value of using Puppeteer.

Unfortunately just setting the value like below doesn't work since the website doesn't detect changes to the field:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="price"]').forEach(function(item) {
        item.value = "14,50";
    });
});
```

So I've discovered I have to use `focus()` and `keyboard.type()`. The problem I'm running into is that the input field don't have unique names and I don't know how to write a `focus()` selector that loops through the inputs.

```
<input _ngcontent-lhe-c73="" id="id" type="text" name="price" autocomplete="off" class="price-input" placeholder="vul de prijs in">
```

```js
const inputs = await page.$eval('.price-input');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelectorAll('input[name="price"]')[i].value = ''; });
    await page.focus('input[name="price"]['+i+']'); // this is invalid
    await page.keyboard.type('14,50');
}
```

How do I write a `focus()` selector to select the correct value in the loop? I've been trying with nth-child but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Would you mean `page.$$('.price-input')` instead of `page.$eval('.price-input')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const inputs = await page.$$('.price-input');
for (const input of inputs) {
    await page.evaluate((element) => { element.value = ''; }, input);
    await input.focus(); // May be redundant as we use the element for typing below.
    await input.type('14,50');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Much easier to work with like this. Unfortunately the site in question still doesn't recognize changes to the field so I still have to find a way around that 